# Why am I experiencing a delay in the sendtransaction method?

Tags: send-transaction

I create a signature with the sendtransaction method. I see a difference between the signature creation time on my local and the time on the network. Usually, it appears 5-10 seconds later on the network (Signature creation time)

I haven't found the reason yet. Should we not add Blockhash or something else?

```
const fs = __importStar(require("fs"));
const raydium_1 = require("./raydium");
const web3_js_1 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const spl_token_1 = require("@solana/spl-token");
const types_1 = require("./types");
const mints_1 = require("./mints");
const tiny_invariant_1 = __importDefault(require("tiny-invariant"));
const connection_1 = __importDefault(require("./utils/connection"));
if (process.argv.length < 6) {
    console.log(`Usage: node ${process.argv[1]} privateKeyFile COIN buySell sellAmt`);
    process.exit();
}
const [, , fileStr, coin, buySell, sellAmt, buyAmt] = process.argv;
async function getAssociatedTokAcc(tokenId, owner) {
    return await spl_token_1.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(spl_token_1.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, spl_token_1.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, mints_1.MINTS[tokenId], owner);
}
async function checkOrCreateAssociatedTokAcc(tokenId, owner) {
    const mint = mints_1.MINTS[tokenId];
    const acc = await spl_token_1.Token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(spl_token_1.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, spl_token_1.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, mint, owner);
    const accInfo = await connection_1.default.getAccountInfo(acc, 'singleGossip');
    if (accInfo) {
        // g
    }
    else {
        // create it and init
        const createIx = spl_token_1.Token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(spl_token_1.ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, spl_token_1.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, mint, acc, owner, owner);
        return [createIx];
    }
    
    return [];
}
async function doSwap() {
    const keyStr = fs.readFileSync(fileStr, 'utf8');
    const privateKey = JSON.parse(keyStr);
    const keypair = web3_js_1.Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(privateKey));
    const aptTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokAcc(types_1.TokenID.APT, keypair.publicKey);
    const usdcTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokAcc(types_1.TokenID.USDC, keypair.publicKey);

    const conn = connection_1.default;
    const isBuy = buySell === 'buy';
    const mainTokenType = {
        APT: types_1.TokenID.APT,

    }[coin];
    (0, tiny_invariant_1.default)(mainTokenType);
    const tokenAccounts = {
        APT: aptTokenAccount,
        USDC: usdcTokenAccount,
    };
    const mainTokenAcc = tokenAccounts[mainTokenType];
    (0, tiny_invariant_1.default)(mainTokenAcc);
    const getSwapper = {
        APT: () => raydium_1.RAYDIUM_APT_USDC_MARKET,
    }[coin];
    (0, tiny_invariant_1.default)(getSwapper);
    const swapper = getSwapper();
    const tokenBAcc = tokenAccounts[swapper.tokenIdB];
    (0, tiny_invariant_1.default)(tokenBAcc);
    const buyTokenID = isBuy ? mainTokenType : swapper.tokenIdB;
    const buyTokenAcc = isBuy ? mainTokenAcc : tokenBAcc;
    const sellTokenID = isBuy ? swapper.tokenIdB : mainTokenType;
    const sellTokenAcc = isBuy ? tokenBAcc : mainTokenAcc;
    const swapperType = {
        APT: types_1.SwapperType.Single,
    }[coin];
    (0, tiny_invariant_1.default)(swapperType);
    const ixs = await checkOrCreateAssociatedTokAcc(mainTokenType, keypair.publicKey);
    const tradeIxs = await swapper.createSwapInstructions(sellTokenID, parseFloat(sellAmt) * mints_1.DECIMALS[sellTokenID], sellTokenAcc, buyTokenID, parseFloat(buyAmt) * mints_1.DECIMALS[buyTokenID], buyTokenAcc, keypair.publicKey);
    const tradeTx = new web3_js_1.Transaction();

  const maxUnits = 1_000_000;
  const totalPriorityFee = 0.00003; // TODO change price as desired
  const totalInLamports = totalPriorityFee*web3_js_1.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
  const microLamportsPrice = totalInLamports*1_000_000/maxUnits;
  const cbpLimitIx = web3_js_1.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
    units: maxUnits,
  });
  const cbpPriceIx = web3_js_1.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: microLamportsPrice,
  });
  tradeTx.add(cbpLimitIx, cbpPriceIx);

  // adding instructions
    tradeTx.add(...ixs, ...tradeIxs);
    const sig = await conn.sendTransaction(tradeTx, [keypair], {
        skipPreflight: true,
        preflightCommitment: 'singleGossip',
        
    });

    console.log(sig);
    process.exit();
}
doSwap();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can help us out by telling us if you're using a default RPC or something you've setup? As well you may be underpricing the priority fee due to congestion.

The most likely culprit is the RPC, however if you're trading a contentious market you may be underpricing your bid for priority.

Happy to revise this answer with more information if you provide it.